# What abi to include for tablets in build.gradle

Tags: android, apk

I am creating an application only for tablets which abi should i include ?
Currently my apk lib folder size is 10.1 MB with following abi X86, armeabi, armeabi-v7a, arm64-b8a, X86_64. I need to reduce the lib folder size, I created app only for tablets.

Comment: sugggestions pls

Comment: 10 MB is a fair size for an android application. If you want to make your app smaller, you can build multiple apks for different types of devices with different CPU architecture. You can read more at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits

Comment: A tablet can use any CPU. Similarly, a phone can use any CPU, and an Android television set-top box can use any CPU. Your decision on CPU has little to do with screen size. On the whole, ARM CPUs are much more common.